# How do I retrieve an object from Parse using WhereEqualTo() using two strings that match the object?

Tags: android

I am having trouble using WhereEqualTo() method in my android Studio.

So in Parse, I have a class named "Room". Each objects in "Room" has numbers of variables columns as course , number, etc.

Then I want to retrieve certain object that matches two columns, course and number. (Ex. if I user chooses math and 101 , I want to get all the objects from Room class that has math AND 101 columns).

So I used

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> roomQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Room");
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("course" , courseName);
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("number" , courseNumber);
```

But I get no matching items even though they exist in Parse.

Here is my entire code.

```
public class SearchResult extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button createBtn;
    Button searchBtn;
    Button myGroupBtn;
    Button settingBtn;


    String[] courses;
    List<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
    // when CREAT button is tapped
    public void createBtn(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Create.class);
        // Removes animation
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    // when Setting button is tapped
    public void settingBtn(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class);
        // Removes animation
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String courseName = intent.getStringExtra("courseName");
        String courseNumber = intent.getStringExtra("courseNumber");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result);
        // Making Links to Buttons on Create
        createBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createBtn);
        searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        myGroupBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myGroupBtn);
        settingBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingBtn);


        //Chaning the button colors
        searchBtn.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        createBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);
        myGroupBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);
        settingBtn.setTextColor(0xFFBFBFBF);

        listView= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(courseName + " " + courseNumber);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> roomQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Room");
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("course" , courseName);
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("number" , courseNumber);

        roomQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    for (ParseObject room : objects) {

                        Log.i("Appinfo", String.valueOf(room.get("title")));
                        String stringToAdd = "";
                        stringToAdd = stringToAdd + String.valueOf(room.get("studyDate")) + "   " +
                                String.valueOf(room.get("category")) + "    " + String.valueOf(room.get("opened") +"\n")
                                + String.valueOf(room.get("title")) +
                                "            "
                        ;
                        listItems.add(stringToAdd);
                        Log.i("Appinfo", "A");
                    }


                } else {
                    Log.i("Appinfo", "B");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        initList();
    }
    public void initList(){

        Log.i("Appinfo", "C");



        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_list, R.id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , roomDetail.class);

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: That should be the way to go, make sure through the debugger that  courseName and courseNumber variables are what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

If `courseNumber` is `Number` type at Parse, the type of variable that you put in `whereEqualto` must be an integer.

You currently put string in the parameter. It should be

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> roomQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Room");
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("course" , courseName);
        roomQuery.whereEqualTo("number" , Integer.parseInt(courseNumber));
```

This might be your problem, I guess.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: still not working. Number column in our parse is String type since we wanna also include numbers starting with 0 such as 012, 079.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way .

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> roomQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Room");
```